# Thrust consideration in sprinkler and irrigation systems

Tags: systems-design, thrust

In commercial fire sprinkler systems or large farm irrigation systems, is the thrust produced by the water a major design consideration? At what stage in the design process is this taken into account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Product design often involves juggling many parameters at the same time, prioritizing them, then testing a design. In sprinklers themselves, the forces associated with the thrust are much lower that the forces the sprinkler experiences during assembly or from internal pressure; so typically they are not a design priority.

For irrigation sprinklers the thrust is not a big consideration in the structural design, because the flow, and resultant thrust is comparatively small. It is however important for [impact sprinklers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_sprinkler), as it is their method of operation.

Fire sprinklers themselves don't generate a lot of force, but there is a lot of dynamic force on the [pipe supports](http://wermac.org/steel/pipesupports.html) on large diameter pipes that turn corners to deliver water to the sprinklers. Fluids can exert very large forces without being a free jet. Here is a big nasty document on [pipe engineering](http://www.wermac.org/pdf/piping_engineering.pdf) that might make your thermo fluids homework look nicer ;-)